# Ant ftp task QUOT command

Tags: ant, ftp

Is there any way to get the Ant ftp task to send a `QUOT` command to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Dont think it is supported. This Bugzilla [shows it was requested but not implemented](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40261)